# iOS Bluetooth State Preservation and Restoration's DUPLICATE ISSUE -25299

Tags: ios, bluetooth, duplicates, core-bluetooth, state-restoration

I am having an issue when instantiating my CBCentralManager. I get a "duplicate issue" message when monitoring it from the iOS console (it does not show in the XCode console).

I've tried updating the **queue name** and the **restoration key id** without success. This is how I instantiate my Central Manager:

```
CBCentralManager *central = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate: self 
    queue: dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.myapp.scanner", NULL)
    options: @{
        CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: @"hexa-string-comes-here"
    }];
```

And those are the errors I am getting:

> CKLs-iPhone-5S **securityd**[78] : 
>   securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler MyApp[2571] add The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -25299 - duplicate item
>   O,genp,E99372E2,L,ck,X2W6M5UYJ9.com.mydomain.myapp,0,acct,svce,v_Data,20151218165347.298588Z,2CAE5650)
>
> CKLs-iPhone-5S **MyApp**[2571] :  SecOSStatusWith
>   error:[-25299] The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error
>   -25299 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error -25299 - duplicate item
>   O,genp,E99372E2,L,ck,X2W6M5UYJ9.com.mydomain.myapp,0,acct,svce,v_Data,20151218165347.298588Z,2CAE5650))

Any ideas?

Comment: What does happen when you name your queue differently (e.g. `"com.mydomain.myapp.scanner1_fkou3h4t"`)?

Comment: Nothing seems to change, @MichaelDorner

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the [`CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Central_Manager_Initialization_Options), you must

1. implement the method

   ```
   // in Objective-C
   - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)dict

   // or in Swift
   func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject])
   ```

   from [`CBCentralManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/), and
2. use the background mode *Uses Bluetooth LE accessories* set up in Xcode:

   [image]

Comment: what is the use of CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to known [Keychain issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4743). (However, it is only a guess that this is Keychain coming from Security log in your app). OSStatus duplicate item appears when there is already a registered item with all attributes supplied along with the item. So what could happen in here is:

1. keychain failed to delete last restoration id - item is left in keychain.
2. register for the restoration with the same id
3. keychain tries to save item.
4. it returns duplicate item error